# COM co-class per-user registration

Tags: vbscript, com, ole, manual, registrykey

Need to implement per-user registration of a COM co-class by adding registry entries to the HKCU registry hive (XP SP3, Windows 7, Windows 8). What is the minimal set of required registry entries to create an object instance by calling the VBScript CreateObject function?

UPD: VBScript implementation

```
Sub RegisterComObject(Path, ProgId, ClsId)
    Dim Shell
    Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    Shell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Classes\" & ProgId & "\", ""
    Shell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Classes\" & ProgId & "\CLSID\", ClsId

    Shell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\" & ClsId & "\", ""
    Shell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\" & ClsId & "\InprocServer32\", Path
    Shell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\" & ClsId & "\ProgID\", ProgID
End Sub

Sub UnregisterComObject(ProgId, ClsId)
    Dim Shell
    Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    Shell.RegDelete "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\" & ClsId & "\InprocServer32\"
    Shell.RegDelete "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\" & ClsId & "\ProgId\"
    Shell.RegDelete "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\" & ClsId & "\"

    Shell.RegDelete "HKCU\Software\Classes\" & ProgId & "\CLSID\"
    Shell.RegDelete "HKCU\Software\Classes\" & ProgId & "\"
End Sub
```

Comment: The exact same minimum you need for HKLM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

1. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{your-CLSID-goes-here}` branch with subkey `InprocServer32` (or, `LocalServer32`) with [its regular syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\{your-ProgID-goes-here}` to map your `ProgID` to `CLSID` in order for `CreateObject` to succeed.

Comment: Thanks. But the ProcessMonitor tool shows that wscript.exe doesn't attempt to lookup my ProgID in HCKU. It starts with HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, then fails and throws error 800A01AD. Windows 7 x64.

Comment: And your `wscript` version is 32 or 64-bit? That is, is this `C:\Windows\system32\wcsript.exe` or `C:\Windows\syswow64\wcsript.exe`?

Comment: Sorry :) I've tested with 64-bit wscript. 
All works perfectly.